# Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, json, listview

here is my list View Activity code
listview:

```
private static String url = "http://xxx.x.x.xxx/index.php";
String categ = null;
private static final String name = "name";
private static final String Category = "Category";

ListView lv;

String returnString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_listview);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    categ = b.getString("category_name");

    new ProgressTask(ListDataActivity.this).execute();

}


class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    {
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "INTERNET CONNECTION NOT PRESENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            startActivity(new Intent(ListDataActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class));
        }

    }

    // private List<Message> messages;
    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        context = activity;
    }

    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, 0).show();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                R.layout.row_listitem, new String[] { name, Category },
                new int[] { R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor }) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {

                    // This a new view we inflate the new layout

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem,
                            null);
                }

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (position % 2 == 1) {

                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(120, 151, 66));
                } else {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(86, 107, 129));
                }
                return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            }
        };

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) lv
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                String name = map.get("name");
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListDataActivity.this,
                        DataViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("itemName", name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        url = url + "?cat_name=" + categ;
        Log.d("", url);

        baseAdapter jParser = new baseAdapter();

        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        if (json != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    String vtype = c.getString(name);
                    String vfuel = c.getString(Category);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Add child node to HashMap key & value
                    map.put(name, vtype);
                    map.put(Category, vfuel);

                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

base class

```
public class baseAdapter {

static InputStream iStream = null;
static JSONArray jarray = null;
static String json = "";

public baseAdapter() {
}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse String to JSON object
    try {
        jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jarray;

}
```

my question is i am passing `categ` from android to php and showing data in list view its working fine but problem is on backpressed when i pass new data to this activity it shows same result in listview on the bases of first data that i passed from previous activity..

Comment: what is his problem?

Comment: Does the `Log.d("", url);` print your desired request url second time?

Comment: yup it prints second time but result same as first time

Comment: i have edited and add base adapter classs